# Input pattern - Mobile number - Start with a specific numbers and character

Tags: reactjs, input

I'm working with react js and i have a input field type tel the backend was designed to accept the phone number starting with +251 if it doesn't start with that it will not send. so what attribute can i add to make that happen and to be visible like a placeholder but character "+251" are in the input the user cant change it but add on to it?

Answer (score 0):

Found this for you https://www.30secondsofcode.org/css/s/input-with-prefix, just an example of how you can handle this with a span next to your input